# Copy and Paste arrays from one spreadsheet based on first column

Tags: arrays, excel

Hopefully this makes sense:
I have a "master" spreadsheet with items 1-100 in columns. item 1 (for example) has 4 columns under it (so A1:D1 is merged, but  from row 2 down, they are still individual columns). item 2 is just a single columns, but 3 has 2 columns under it. There is no rhyme or reason to the items or how many columns are under it, but they won't change.

I'm looking for a way to go to another tab (call it sheet1) and type the numbers i want at the top of the page in single cells (1, 15, 35, 84, 99) and have the macro copy the appropriate columns from "master" and paste them in order.

Hopefully this makes sense and is easy. I was thinking defining "1" in the "master" tab as cells A1:D26 and whenever there is a "1" in "sheet1" it copies the array and paste it, then goes to the next number "15" and does the same thing that is already defined. I'd have to somehow define all the arrays, but like i said, those won't change.

any suggestions would be great.

thanks

adam

Comment: Do you want to figure out the ranges automatically or do you plan to hard-wire them in your code (most likely you will want to use VBA for this - if I'm right you might want to edit question to tag accordingly).

Comment: Second question - do you want to over-write your `1,15,35,84,99` or do you want the copy to start below that?

Comment: If I can define them with the VBA that would be great. I if i need to hard-write them i could also. Starting below the 1,15,35,84,99 would be better i think because if i need to add a number "22" lets say i can just move the "35,84,99" over and add the 22 and re-run the macro would assume.

Answer (score 0):

The following code should do exactly what you are asking for; I don't think it needs explanation beyond what is in the variable names and comments.

```
Option Explicit

Sub copyMerged()
Dim wsMaster As Worksheet
Dim wsTarget As Worksheet
Dim rNumbers As Range
Dim rSource As Range
Dim rDest As Range

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set wsMaster = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Master")
Set wsTarget = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

' delete all cells below first row
' otherwise we'll run in trouble with merged cells
wsTarget.Range([2:2], wsTarget.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell)).Delete
Set rNumbers = wsTarget.[A1]
Set rDest = wsTarget.[A2]
While Not IsEmpty(rNumbers)
  Set rSource = getRange(wsMaster, Int(rNumbers.Value))
  Set rNumbers = rNumbers.Offset(0, 1)
  rSource.Copy
  rDest.PasteSpecial
  Set rDest = rDest.Offset(0, 1).Cells(1, 1)
Wend

End Sub

Function getRange(ws As Worksheet, v As Integer) As Range
' return the vth merged cell in top row of ws
' and return the range from there to the bottom
Dim ii
Dim r As Range
Set r = ws.[A1]

For ii = 1 To v - 1
  Set r = r.Offset(0, 1)
Next ii

' select the entire merged cell... a bit weird
Set r = Range(r, r.Offset(0, 1).Offset(0, -1))

' extend to the last cell in the block below this
Dim r2 As Range
Set r2 = r.Offset([A:A].Rows.Count - 1, 0).End(xlUp)

Set getRange = Range(r, r2)

End Function
```

Comment: Happy I could help. You may choose to "accept" the answer by clicking the little check mark.